# Typescript use Map or Object

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am currently doing a basic Pizza Delivery App. So you click on a Pizza you want and it gets added to a list, which is grouping the results.

So it should display:

Pizza Margarita 2x
Pizza Salame    1x

I thought about doing a Map like `Map<Pizza, number>` where Pizza is my object and the number is the amount.

However this doesnt feel right. Also I can't iterate with ngFor through it.

So wouldn't it just be easy to create an object, like:
{ "pizza": Pizza, "amount": 2} and put this in an array?

Comment: *"wouldn't it just be easy to create an object"* - that sounds pretty easy, so what's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very much up to your use case.

> So wouldn't it just be easy to create an object, like: { "pizza":
>   Pizza, "amount": 2} and put this in an array?

You will have to search the Array if you want to get a specific item out of it and you don't know the index.

The benefit of `Map`s is that you get fast lookup and can use `Object`s as keys instead of just `String`s.

```js
class Pizza {};

// Using Map
const orderMap = new Map();
const margaritaPizza = new Pizza();
const salamePizza = new Pizza();

orderMap.set(margaritaPizza, 2);
orderMap.set(salamePizza, 1);

console.log(`Margarita ammount: ${orderMap.get(margaritaPizza)}`);
console.log(`Salame ammount: ${orderMap.get(salamePizza)}`);

// Using Array
const orderArr = [];

orderArr.push({
  pizza: "margaritaPizza",
  ammount: 2
});

orderArr.push({
  pizza: "salamePizza",
  ammount: 1
});

console.log(`Margarita ammount: ${orderArr.find(el => el.pizza === "margaritaPizza").ammount}`);
console.log(`Salame ammount: ${orderArr.find(el => el.pizza === "salamePizza").ammount}`);
```

---

Additionally, you say:

> I thought about doing a Map like Map where Pizza is my
>   object and the number is the amount.
>
> However this doesnt feel right. Also I can't iterate with ngFor
>   through it.

`Map` implements [`@@iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@iterator) and can be converted to a plain `Array` using `Array.from()`.